# returning null when using value out of block

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to query one collection, get IDs from that and with that I am querying another collection and send the response. No issue in that. My issue is I am using foreach, so I am trying to get the value out of block and send the response. But it's throwing `null`. I consoled the value inside the block, its giving the response but I couldn't access the value out of the block.

**Code**

```
getDetails = async (req, res) => {
    let data: any[] = [];
    await employee.find({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)
    }, (err, obj) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("No Such Employee")
        } else {
            obj.forEach(element => {
                employer.find({
                    user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(element.user)
                }, (err, details) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("No such  employer")
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
                            let p_info = {
                                "id": detail._id,
                                "fname": details[i].fname "lname": details[i].lname "phone": details[i].phone,
                                "email": details[i].email,
                            }
                            data.push(p_info); // I can get value here

                        }

                    }

                })

            });
            res.send(data); // Cannot get value here
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: How can more than one object have the same _id, `_id` should be unique.

Comment: Asynchronous operations inside a `.forEach()` where you need the results from all of them will simply not work.  Your `.forEach()` loop finishes executing before ANY of the async operations inside the loop have finished.  Thus `data` is empty when you try to send it.  Your best chance is to use the promise interface for ALL your database operations (no plain callbacks).  Then, use a plain `for` loop instead of `.forEach()` and you can use `await` on the async operations (that return promises) to be able to collect all the results which you can send after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

return response only when all your asynchronous db calls are done. see below:

```js
getDetails = async(req, res) => {
  let data = [];
  let employees;
  try {
    employees = await employee.find({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("No Such Employee");
  }
  let emp_len = employees.length;
  employees.forEach((emp_obj, idx) => {
    let details = await employer.find({
      user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(emp_obj.user)
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < patient.length; i++) {
      let p_info = {
        "id": patient._id,
        "fname": details[i].fname,
        "lname": details[i].lname,
        "phone": details[i].phone,
        "email": details[i].email,
      }
      data.push(p_info); // I can get value here
    }
    if (emp_len == idx + 1) {
      res.send(data); // Cannot get value here
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This really isn't the right way to do things as `.forEach()` does not wait for `await`.  Use a regular `for` loop instead of `.forEach()`.  Also, your  error handling on `employee.find()` makes no sense as you're continuing to try to process `employees` even where there was an error getting it.

Comment: still I am getting null @vikash